# Stop body scroll when off canvas menu active

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm facing with scrolling, which is explained below. I'm still working on the mobile site, haven't made it to desktop just yet. The off-canvas menu is a modified version of [this](https://codepen.io/kyunwang/details/zNOoxb) with the 'Reveal' Effect.

**Problem**

When scrolling on mobile, after the first swipe motion, the website 'snaps' (no CSS snapping applied)

- When swiping from top to bottom, it snaps to almost the bottom. I have to swipe twice.
- When swiping from bottom to top, it snaps to below the logo. I have to swipe twice.
- This will also occur on the off-canvas menu where you can see I have to swipe twice to get to the bottom.

**What I've tried**

If I remove the height (see code below), the snap issue goes away, so one swipe up/down will work without issue.

```
html,
body,
.off-canvas,
.main-body,
.main-container {
    height: 100%;
}
```

**However, this now adds a problem with my off-canvas menu**. When scrolling down the menu, the main body will scroll along with it. Is there a way to add something in vanilla JS to stop this from occurring? I've tried a few things work overflow but with no luck (may have implemented it wrong).

**Desired outcome**

- To be able to swipe in one motion without snapping
- Off-canvas menu to be independent of the main container. So when a user scrolls on it, it will long go as far as the contents of the menu, and the main container will remain fixed so it doesn't move when the off-canvas is open.
- The https://ASOS.com mobile website off canvas menu is something that would best describe the above. When their menu is open, you can't scroll on the body and the menu is fixed to it's own height rather than the main container.

In the CSS, I've made note of where the issue is likely to be with 'Stack Overflow Start' and 'Stack Overflow End'. The JS is at the very end of the HTML. Avoiding jquery (want to keep to vanilla JS). Would appreciate any code I can implement/amend/remove if JS as I'm still quite new to it

Thank you!

## HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Site</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <style>
            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Quicksand';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 400;
                font-display: swap;
                src: local('Quicksand'),
                    url('../fonts/Quicksand-Regular.woff2') format('woff2');
            }
            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Quicksand';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 600;
                font-display: swap;
                src: local('Quicksand-SemiBold'),
                    url('../fonts/Quicksand-SemiBold.woff2') format('woff2');
            }
            body {
                font-family: 'Quicksand', Fallback, sans-serif;
            }
        </style>
        
        <div id="off-canvas" class="off-canvas">    
            <nav class="oc-menu oc-effect">
                <h2>Sidebar</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 8</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 9</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 10</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 11</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 12</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 13</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <div class="main-body">
                <div class="main-container">
                    
                    <!-- NAVBAR -->
                    
                    <header>
                        <div class="navbar">
                            <div class="logo">
                                <h4>Site</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="header-icons">
                                <div class="basket">
                                    <img src="img/shopping-cart.svg" alt="shopping cart image" draggable="false" class="basket-img">
                                    <p class="basket-text">Basket</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="hamburger">
                                    <img src="img/hamburger.svg" alt="hamburger menu" draggable="false" class="hamb" data-effect="oc-effect">
                                    <p class="hamburger-menu" data-effect="oc-effect">Menu</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <!-- Search Form Top -->
                        
                        <div class="sft">
                            <form role="search" class="sft-form">
                                <span class="sft-search-svg">
                                    <svg width="13pt" height="13pt" version="1.1" viewBox="-1 0 136 136.22" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m93.148 80.832c16.352-23.09 10.883-55.062-12.207-71.41s-55.062-10.883-71.41 12.211c-16.348 23.09-10.883 55.059 12.211 71.406 16.48 11.668 38.27 12.566 55.652 2.3008l37.77 37.543c4.0781 4.293 10.863 4.4648 15.156 0.38672 4.293-4.0742 4.4648-10.859 0.39063-15.152-0.12891-0.13672-0.25391-0.26172-0.39063-0.39063zm-41.84 3.5c-18.246 0.003907-33.039-14.777-33.051-33.023-0.003906-18.246 14.777-33.039 33.027-33.047 18.223-0.007813 33.008 14.75 33.043 32.973 0.03125 18.25-14.742 33.066-32.996 33.098h-0.023437z"/>
                                    </svg>
                                </span>
                                <input type="search" name="q" class="sft-input" placeholder="Search For..." aria-label="Search through site content" autocomplete="off">
                                <button class="sft-btn">Search</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sm">
                            <a href="#">Item 1</a>
                            <a href="#">Item 2</a>
                            <a href="#">Item 3</a>
                            <a href="#">Item 4</a>
                            <a href="#">Item 5</a>
                            <a href="#">Item 6</a>
                            <a href="#">Item 7</a>
                            <a href="#">Item 8</a>
                        </div>
                    </header>
                    
                    <main>
                    
                    </main>
                    
                    <!-- Footer -->
                
                    <footer>
                        
                        <div class="footer-logo_1">
                            <h1>Site</h1>
                        </div>
                        
                        <hr>
                        
                        <div class="footer-nav_2">
                            <div class="footer-nav-item">Item 1</div>
                            <div class="footer-nav-item">Item 2</div>
                            <div class="footer-nav-item">Item 3</div>
                            <div class="footer-nav-item">Item 4</div>
                            <div class="footer-nav-item">Item 5</div>
                            <div class="footer-nav-item">Item 6</div>
                            <div class="footer-nav-item">Item 7</div>
                            <div class="footer-nav-item">Item 8</div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <hr>
                        
                        <div class="footer-payment-icons">
                            <img src="img/Visa.svg" class="footer-payment-icons-img">
                            <img src="img/Mastercard.svg" class="footer-payment-icons-img">
                            <img src="img/Amex.svg" class="footer-payment-icons-img">
                            <img src="temp/PayPal.svg" class="footer-payment-icons-img">
                            <img src="img/ApplePay.svg" class="footer-payment-icons-img">
                            <img src="img/GPay.svg" class="footer-payment-icons-img">
                        </div>
                        
                        <hr>
                        
                        <div class="footer-copyright-privacy">
                            <p style="text-align: center"> Copyright &copy; 2020 - <span style="font-weight: 600;">Site</span></p>
                            <div class="privacy">
                                <p>Privacy Policy</p>
                                <p>Terms &amp; Conditions</p>
                                <p>Sitemap</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </footer>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
        <script>
            var click = document.querySelectorAll('.hamb, .testing');
            var menu = document.querySelector('#off-canvas');
            var pusher = document.querySelector('.main-body');
            var effect;

            for (var i = 0; i < click.length; i++) {
              click[i].addEventListener('click', addClass)
            }

            pusher.addEventListener('click', closeMenu);

            function addClass(e) {
              effect = e.target.getAttribute('data-effect');
              menu.classList.toggle(effect);
              menu.classList.toggle('oc-menu-open');
              }

            function closeMenu(el) {
              if (el.target.classList.contains('main-body')) {
                menu.classList.toggle(effect);
                menu.classList.toggle('oc-menu-open');
              } 
            }
        </script>
    </body>
```

## CSS

```
*,::after,::before{box-sizing:border-box},ol[class],ul[class]{padding:0}blockquote,body,dd,dl,figcaption,figure,h1,h2,h3,h4,li,ol[class],p,ul[class]{margin:0}body{min-height:100vh;scroll-behavior:smooth;text-rendering:optimizeSpeed;line-height:1.5;}ol[class],ul[class]{list-style:none}ol,ul{list-style:none;padding-left:0;}a:not([class]){text-decoration-skip-ink:auto}img{max-width:100%;display:block}article>*+*{margin-top:1em}button,input,select,textarea{font:inherit}@media (prefers-reduced-motion:reduce){*{animation-duration:0s!important;animation-iteration-count:1!important;transition-duration:0s!important;scroll-behavior:auto!important}}

textarea,
input.text,
input[type="text"],
input[type="button"],
input[type="submit"],
.input-checkbox {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input, button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/** Stack Overflow Start **/

html,
body,
.off-canvas,
.main-body,
.main-container {
    height: 100%;
}

.main-body{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background: #fbfbfb;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.main-body::after {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    content: '';
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s, width 0.1s 0.5s, height 0.1s 0.5s;
    transition: opacity 0.5s, width 0.1s 0.5s, height 0.1s 0.5s;
}

.off-canvas {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.oc-menu-open .main-body::after {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.oc-menu {
    overflow: scroll;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #663399;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.oc-menu::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    content: '';
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.oc-menu-open .oc-menu::after {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s, width 0.1s 0.5s, height 0.1s 0.5s;
    transition: opacity 0.5s, width 0.1s 0.5s, height 0.1s 0.5s;
}

.oc-menu h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.oc-menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 1em 1em 1em 1.2em;
    color: inherit;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 600;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
    transition: background 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.oc-menu ul li:first-child a {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), inset 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.oc-effect.oc-menu-open .main-body {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(80%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(80%, 0, 0);
}

.oc-effect.oc-menu {
    z-index: 1;
}

.oc-effect.oc-menu-open .oc-effect.oc-menu{
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}

/** Stack Overflow End **/








/*****

Custom Code 

******/

body {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #663399;
}


/** NavBar **/

header {
    background-color: #663399;
}

.navbar {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 15px 0px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 60% 40%;
}

.logo {
    padding-left: 10px;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center start;
}

.header-icons {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.basket, .hamburger {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
    place-items: center center;
    grid-row-gap: px;
}

.basket-img, .hamb, .basket-text, .hamburger-menu {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.hamb {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: -10px;
    max-width: 65%;
    -webkit-filter: invert(100%); /* safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
    filter: invert(100%);
}

.basket-text, .hamburger-menu {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0.2em;     
    margin: -0.2em; 
}

.sft-form {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;   
    padding: 5px 10px 12.5px 10px;
}

.sft-search-svg, .sft-input, .sft-btn {
    height: 40px;
}

.sft-search-svg {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center center;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    border-right: solid 1px #dddddd;
}

.sft-search-svg svg {
    margin: 0 8px;
    fill: #7D7D8C;
}

.sft-input {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    padding-left: 10px; 
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-radius: 0;
}

.sft-input:placeholder-shown {
    font-size: 14px;
}

.sft-input:focus {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(21, 156, 228, 0.4);
}

.sft-btn {
    background-color: #0BC133;
    color: inherit;
    font-weight: 600;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-left: 0;
}

.sft-suggestions {
    padding: 5px 7.5px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    color: #7d7d8c;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.sft-sug-item:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}

/** Scroll Nav **/

.sm {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.sm a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sm a:hover {
  background-color: #777;
}

/** Main Content **/

main {
    height: 100vh;
}


/** Footer **/

footer {
    display: grid;
    grid-row-gap: 20px;
    background-color: #663399;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 15px;
    grid-row-gap: 20px;

}

.footer-logo_1 {
    padding-top: 20px;
    display: grid;
}

.footer-logo_1 h1 {
    font-size: 1.4em;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.footer-logo_1 p {
    font-size: 14px;
}

/** Footer Nav Links **/

.footer-nav_2 {
    padding: 0 5px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-row-gap: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.footer-nav-item {
    padding: 2px;
}

/** Footer Payment Icons **/

.footer-payment-icons {
    padding: 0 15px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
    place-items: center center;
}

.footer-payment-icons-img {
    max-width: 70%;
}

/** Footer Copyright **/

.footer-copyright-privacy {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

/** Footer Privacy **/

.privacy {
    font-size: 12px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
    grid-column-gap: 7.5px;
    color: #d3d3d3;
    justify-content: center;
}

/** Temporary **/

hr {
    height: 1px;
    width: 80%;
}
```

Comment: Set a class to body with overflow:hidden when you turn on the menu

Comment: @Konowy with the above code, how can I apply overflow hidden to the body once the menu is active?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. https://codepen.io/KonradLinkowski/pen/zYqNXYx

JavaScript

```
function addClass(e) {
  effect = e.target.getAttribute('data-effect');
  menu.classList.toggle(effect);
  menu.classList.toggle('oc-menu-open');

  document.body.classList.toggle('menu-is-open')
}

function closeMenu(el) {
  if (el.target.classList.contains('main-body')) {
    menu.classList.toggle(effect);
    menu.classList.toggle('oc-menu-open');

    document.body.classList.toggle('menu-is-open')
  }
}
```

CSS

```
.main-body.menu-is-open {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for typing that up! Sadly still no luck. Just had a thought. When I remove .main-body{height:100%} and keep the other heights, I get the desired effect on the scroll bar for the menu but it removes scrolling on the main body. With JS, would it be possible to remove .main-body{height:100%} only when the menu is active and enable it when the menu is closed?

Comment: I didn't know that your scroll is on .main-body. Changing the css and some js helped.

Comment: Thanks, Konowy! It won't close the menu when clicking anywhere on the .main-body area. Any ideas why?

Answer (score -1):

```
   body {
      overflow: hidden;
   }
```

I hope this works !

Comment: Please read the full question. Adding overflow: hidden by default will cause the page to not scroll even if menu is closed.

Comment: sorry for not helping you ;( check the person on top of my answer